# Links shift between linked HTML pages

Tags: html, css, position, spacing

I'm building my first website in HTML and am having some issues keeping consitency between pages.

I have some links in a div at the top of my page. They all work as intended, however between my home page and another page on the website the spacing between each link changes.

I've managed to work out that the shift only happens when the body element in the second page is added. On other pages without a body element the issue does not occur. I am assuming it's something to do with the position style of the body vs the links but I don't understand what the issue is. I have tried various combinations of changing the position from relative to fixed to static and none seem to work.

My body element styling:

```
    body.desc{
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    position: static;
    height: 100px;
    }
```

The link (and links div) styling:

```
    a:link{
    color: #f20202;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: static;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    word-wrap: normal;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    div.links{
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: 700px;

    }
```

Please let me know if you need more detail or other snippets of code.

EDIT code snippets below, let me know if this needs reformatting:

CSS and HTML:

```css
  h2 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

  h3 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

 a:link{
    color: #f20202;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: static;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    word-wrap: normal;
    display: inline-block;
  }

 a:hover{
  color: #00ffff !important
 }

 a:visited{
  color: #f20202
 } 


div.links{
width: 600px;
margin-left: 700px;

}

div.home_images {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

img.plant{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

body.desc{
font-size: 20px;
letter-spacing: 4px;
position: static;
height: 100px;
}

div.listing{
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 1000px;
}

#img-link, #img-link img{
  text-decoration: none !important;
  border:0px !important;
  outline:none;
  border-width: 0px;
  outline-width:0px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#content{
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 600px;
}

div.shop_images {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
###FOR HOME PAGE###
<div class="links">
        <a href="index.html"> HOME!</a>
        <a href="plants.html">PLANTS!</a>
        <a href="about.html">ABOUT!</a>
        <a href="index.html">CART!</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    <h2> 
    <br>
    Hi there! ❀◕ ‿ ◕❀<br>
    <br>
     Have a look around, see if there's anything you like <br>
     <br>
     South London based indoor gardening  *:·.⋆ ꧁ ✿ ☻ ༺☾✧ ˖⁺ ⋆<br>
    </h2>
    <div>
        <div class="home_images">
    <a  id="img-link" href="K_daigremontiana.html">
    <img  id="img-link" class= "home" src="images/IMG_20221012_125729_resize.jpg" alt="Kalanchoe daigremontiana">
    </a>
    <a  id="img-link" href="K_daigremontiana.html">
    <img class= "home" src="images/IMG_20221012_125708_resize.jpg" alt="Adromischus Herrei">
    </a>
    <a  id="img-link" href="K_daigremontiana.html">
    <img class= "home" src="images/IMG_20221012_125650_resize.jpg" alt="Echinofossulocactus pentacanthus">
    </a>
    </div>
    
###FOR SECOND PAGE WITH BODY WHERE LINKS SHIFT###

    <div class="links">
        <a href="index.html"> HOME!</a>
        <a href="plants.html">PLANTS!</a>
        <a href="about.html">ABOUT!</a>
        <a href="index.html">CART!</a>
    </div>


    <div id="content">
        <h3> 
        <br>
         Kalanchoe daigremontiana
        </h3>
        
        <div class="listing">
            <img class= "plant" src="images/IMG_20221012_125729_resize.jpg" alt="Kalanchoe daigremontiana">
            <body class="desc">
                Succulent, native to Madagascar. Goes by a number of other aliases: mother of thousands; crown of thorns;
                alligator plant; Devil's backbone; Mexican hat plant. Striped foliage, leaves develop plantlets on their
                margins which drop and grow into new plants - allowing the plant to spread. 
                <br>
                <br>
                Care: as for most other succulents. Well draining soil, bright indirect light. Water infrequently, reduce watering over Winter.
             </body>

        
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did I understand correctly that you have a HTML document that has no `<body>` tag?

Comment: If would also be good if you could post the HTML code for two pages that behave differently.

Comment: @KWriter The home page has no body as it only contains a sub heading and some images. I had thought that `<body>` was mainly for main sections of text.

Comment: No, take a look at minimal HTML document. It has head and body sections. Here is one link. https://www.sitepoint.com/a-minimal-html-document-html5-edition/

Maybe due to lack of body section CSS code is not executed?

Comment: I've added in body tags and the issue persists. When I remove the (original) body section the issue stops, so all I can think of is that it's something to do with the position tag on some CSS for other sections?

Comment: Did you add "desc" class to the body?

Comment: .... I have now. Thank you so much! (apologies for being so dumb lol)

Comment: You are welcome. No need for apologies. I'm glad that I was able to help. I'll sum things up and add an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your document should have `body` tag and  CSS class `desc` must be assigned to it.